# Why do I lose context in this code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here is the code where I lose the context when using the spread operator.

Look at function "decorator". Line when I lose context is marked with "ERROR"

```
/** MethodDecorator example */
class Account {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;

    public constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    @decorator
    public sayMessage(msg: string): string {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}: ${msg}`
    }
}

function decorator(target: any, key: string, desc: any): any {
    let originDesc = desc.value;

    desc.value = function(...args: any[]): any {
        return originDesc(...args); // ==> ERROR: context lost
        //return originDesc.apply(this, arguments); // ==> all OK
    };
    return desc;
}

let persone = new Account('John', 'Smith');
let message = persone.sayMessage('Hello world!');
console.log(message); // ==> undefined undefined: Hello world!
```

As far as I understand `originDesc(...args);` equals `originDesc.apply(this, arguments);` so why is my context lost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As far as I understand originDesc(...args); equals originDesc.apply(this, arguments); so why context is lost?

No, it doesn't. It's equivalent to `originDesc(args[0], args[1], /*etc.*/)`, which uses the default `this` (the global object in loose mode, `undefined` in strict mode).

In that code, you'll need to use `.apply`:

```
originDesc.apply(appropriateThisValueHere, args);
```

or `.call`:

```
originDesc.call(appropriateThisValueHere, ...args);
```

According to this comment in the code:

> ```
>  //return originDesc.apply(this, arguments); // ==> all OK
> ```

`appropriateThisValue` would be `this`, so either:

```
originDesc.apply(this, args);
```

or

```
originDesc.call(this, ...args);
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you set:

```
let originDesc = desc.value; // This is where you loose context
```

and then call `originDesc`. This is exactly the same case as described here: [How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback).

Also, `originDesc(...args)` compiles into `originDesc.apply(void 0, args)`. (`void` because it has not context binded, you can test it on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)